# Adding condition to DeleteView in Django

Tags: django, django-generic-views

I am learning basics of Django and trying to add a condition before deletion of Ingredient instance in a generic DeleteView.

But it looks like DeleteView is just ignoring my condition. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance for looking at my question!

```
class IngredientDelete(LoginRequiredMixin, DeleteView):
  model = Ingredient
  template_name = "inventory/ingredient_delete_form.html"
  success_url = "/ingredient/list"

  def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    object = self.get_object()
    if len(object.reciperequirement_set.all()) > 0:
      object.delete(save=False)
      messages.error("You can't delete an ingredient if it is used in Menu Items. Please update Menu items first. You can check related Menu items list on the Ingredient Details page")
      return render(request, "ingredient/<pk>", messages)
    else:
      return super().delete(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

in python shell, for the instance object I try `len(object.reciperequirement_set.all())` and get `1`, so I suppose the query in my condition is set correctly.

At local host page for the same Ingredient instance I get the error page:

*ProtectedError at /ingredient/23/delete*

*("Cannot delete some instances of model 'Ingredient' because they are referenced through protected foreign keys: 'RecipeRequirement.ingredient'.", {<RecipeRequirement: menu item: testdel, price: 34.00, ingredient: testingr: 22.00 tsp>})*

*Request Method:    POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/ingredient/23/delete
Django Version: 4.0.4
Exception Type: ProtectedError*

Comment: remove first line `object.delete(save=False)` in if statement.

Comment: thank you! commented that line out; unfortunately, the error still happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override [`test_func()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.mixins.UserPassesTestMixin.test_func) with your own conditions.

Comment: Thank you! I think I am getting somewhere after adding test_func like this:


```
  def test_func(self):
    object = self.get_object()
    if len(object.reciperequirement_set.all()) > 0:
      return False
    else:
      return True
```

Now it redirects the user to 403 error page. Is it what expected?
Trying now to get user redirected to some other page with custom error message by changing "return False" line.

Comment: `HTTP code 403` does not strictly mean an error, but a lack of access to a specific resource. So it works, you can accept the answer.